# Tensor product of two free resolutions yields a free resolution (closed binomial edge ideals)

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, binomial-ideals

I am trying to read the paper Closed binomial edge ideals by Irena Peeva: https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/crelle-2023-0048/html

My question is related to Lemma 4.6, where it is claimed that the minimal free resolution of $S/(N_{b+1}:x_1y_b)$ is the tensor product of the Koszul complex $$\boldsymbol{K}(x_2,\dots,x_{b-1},y_{b+1},\dots,y_c)$$ with the minimal free resolution of $S/M_{b,c+1}$.

So far, the book Graded Syzygies by the same author has helped me a lot. However, I cannot find a reference for the tensor product of a Koszul complex with a free resolution. Unfortunately, I have not found anything in other books (S. Lang, Bruns/Herzog, Eisenbud) in the chapters that deal with the Koszul complex.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you very much!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't formulate it clearly. Why is the equality $F(S/(N_{b+1} : x_1y_b)) = K(x_1,\dots,x_{b-1},y_{b+1},\dots,y_c) \otimes F(S/M_{b,c+1})$ true? The proof uses the fact that $(N_{b+1} : x_1y_b) = (x_1,\dots,x_{b-1},y_{b+1},\dots,y_c) +M_{b,c+1}$ and that the variables $x_1,\dots,x_{b-1},y_{b+1},\dots,y_c$ do not occur as generators of the monomial ideal $M_{b,c+1}$. When do you know that a minimal free resolution is the tensor product of two other minimal free resolutions? And where can i find a reference for this question?